Why does TypeScript not prevent passing of args in the wrong order?
Given these simple wrapper Types, why does TS not error when I pass the arguments in the wrong order?
class FirstName {
    constructor(public value: string) {}
}

class LastName {
    constructor(public value: string) {}
}

function getFullName(fname: FirstName, sname: LastName){
    return `${fname.value} ${sname.value}`;
}

const fName = new FirstName("Dave");
const lName = new LastName("Cook");

var greeting = getFullName(lName, fName); // no compiler error!?!


I would assume it's because a FirstName object satisfies LastName. Typescript is proabably checking type compatibility based on the shape of the objects rather than their declared names. This might allow objects with identical structures to be used interchangeably, even if they represent different concepts

(I updated the comment to expand on my thinking. I am likely wrong however)

that holds up!
If I do this, then I do get a compiler error:
class FirstName {
id:number = 1234
constructor(public value: string) {}
}
class LastName {
    constructor(public value: string) {}
}


Also you could even pass an object in directly to check. getFullName({ value: 'bob' }, { value: 'dob' }) // no compiler error

Typescript is structurally, not nominally, typed. Any object satisfying { value: string } (even with additional properties, except where excess property checks apply because there's no other reference to it) is fine. Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

FirstName and LastName are objects with a value: string property. So everything is logical, because in TypeScript compiler checks only data types, not class names.
